# Comparing different datetime formats

Tags: python, date, datetime

Dataframe 1 named max has data in it`s index

```
max.index
```

DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-01', '2018-01-02', '2018-01-03', '2018-01-04',

'2018-01-05', '2018-01-08', '2018-01-09', '2018-01-10',
   '2018-01-11', '2018-01-12',

...
   '2018-12-17', '2018-12-18', '2018-12-19', '2018-12-20',

'2018-12-21', '2018-12-24', '2018-12-26', '2018-12-27',

'2018-12-28', '2018-12-31'],

dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', length=246, freq=None)

and the second dataframe datex contains

[Timestamp('2019-02-18 00:00:00'),

Timestamp('2019-02-07 00:00:00'),

Timestamp('2019-02-07 00:00:00'),

Timestamp('2019-02-07 00:00:00'),

Timestamp('2019-02-07 00:00:00'),

Timestamp('2019-01-31 00:00:00'),

Timestamp('2019-01-25 00:00:00'),

Timestamp('2019-01-18 00:00:00'),

Timestamp('2019-01-11 00:00:00'),

Timestamp('2018-11-14 00:00:00'),

Timestamp('2018-11-14 00:00:00'),

Timestamp('2018-11-13 00:00:00'),

Timestamp('2018-11-03 00:00:00')]

I want to compare these two using

```
i = 0
for dat in datex:
    if dat==max.index[i]:
        print("yay")
    else:
        print("s")
    i = i + 1
```

, but since both are in different formats I can`t, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: Convert everything into `datetime` objects and compare those.  Have a look at [dateutil](https://opensource.com/article/18/4/python-datetime-libraries#Dateutil)

Comment: Have you tried converting the values in the _datex_ to datetime with `pd.to_datetime()`?

Comment: @Julia Yes did that, the value that you are seeing are the values after pd.to_datetime(). The datetime method is the one adding those 00:00:00

Comment: Do you get an error message when comparing them?

Comment: @Alfe I tried converting everything to datetime, I dont understand the dateutil method though.

Comment: @julia as updated above I just tried that and the output was print("s") block everytime

Comment: Are you trying to compare both dataframes based on the same index? 1st element in _max_ dataframe with the 1st element in _datex_ dataframe? BTW, you should avoid using python names like _max_, _min_ (built-in function names) for your variables. Additionaly, when you do `for dat in datex` this does not return you a date value, it returns a column name.

Comment: @AbhishekPal: **Not one** of the values in `datex` and `max.index` are **equal**?

Comment: @Julia I am comparing the values of index of one dataframe to the values in another dataframe. I have solved it, by applying `pd.to_datetime` twice on datex did the job, don`t know why though, you have any idea?

Comment: @stovfl yes, I have solved the problem, dont know how though

Answer (score 0):

I propose to use the `dateutil` module to convert arbitrary timestamp strings into unified `datetime` objects:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
parse('2018-04-29T17:45:25Z')
```

yields

```
datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 29, 17, 45, 25, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

and

```
parse('2018-04-29')
```

yields

```
datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 29, 0, 0)
```

You can use `Timestamp('2019-02-18 00:00:00').to_pydatetime()` to convert a Pandas `Timestamp` into a `datetime` object.